# Android App Will Not Open

Tags: android, installation, apk

I have just created an Android app in Intellij. It works beautifully on the emulator, which is the same version of Android as I have on my phone (2.3.3) However, when i install the apk file on my phone, it installs fine, but then you can't open the app.

What I mean is that the install finishes and you have a done option but open is grayed out. There is no item in the menu, and there is no shortcut made. I have this in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>

<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:enabled="true">
    <activity android:name="PhlogMain"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".PhlogEditNotes"/>
    <service android:name=".PhlogListenerService"/>
</application>
```

I have the Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830 phone.

Comment: on which android sdk you used to create the app?

Comment: check the sdk version in manifest file according to your version.

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
How do i check it on the phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much work I rebuilt the whole thing, changed the keys and tried again and it worked. I am not really sure where it started to work but at least it is now! :-)